# First page of newest comments cut short

Tags: wordpress, comments

Is there a way to display a full first page of comment results for each post if filtering by newest comments first? E.g. The problem is if I set the comments per page to 10 and a blog post has 11 comments, the first page then only displays 1 result where 10 would be expected.

```
wp_list_comments(array('per_page' => '10, 'reverse_top_level' => true));
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and details of the debugging you have done, so that we have the information we need to be able to help you find and solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @FluffyKitten but it looks like you can replicate this same peculiarity using standard wordpress discussion options in wp-admin and then viewing comments in any comment enabled theme. I have added the code I am using to display comments as if I were to ignore wp-admin.

Comment: The guidelines for using Stack Overflow are that your question should include specific details of the problem you are having, what you have tried yourself to attempt to fix the issue and the relevant code you have used. "*How do I do this?*" is not a suitable question for this site. You are expected to have made a decent attempt at researching & fixing the problem yourself before posting. Your question shows no evidence of either.

Comment: This has been very informative. Thank you.